# how to send and display data from one domain to another?

Tags: javascript, cross-platform

I have my portal on asp.net, my friend have on php. He wants to me to return text data from my database by sending parameter and wants to display it on his portal. I have given him url say abc.com?id=1 for receiving text data. How can he display data returned from abc.com?id=1 on his portal with say "innerhtml" in javascript.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **programming** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Programming questions may be asked at [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can work like this,

In your website with `abc.com?id=1` will read your db data according to `id` the out put the result as `XML` or `JSON` like an API call.

The your friend can read the URL (`abc.com?id=1`)  with JSON or XML parse method in PHP.

This is the way something like many API calls works.

Hope its make sense..